# drupal - problem with quicktabs

Tags: drupal

Hello
I have quite a strange problem using quicktabs.  I used the framework theme to develop a custom look for my site.  I used quicktabs in the center content area to create a tabbed look for placing links within the body.  Everything is working fine.  However, when I view the site in IE8 at a resolution if 1024*768, I have trouble with a few links.  It seems that sometimes the first link under my buttons are difficult to click.  The link is there - I can actually click it, but it is very difficult to locate - it only appears at the very beginning of the link text - it is not the first letter, it seems to be only the first pixel.

I looked at the source and everything seems to be correct - I can't figure out what could be wrong.
Has anyone seen any similar behavior that might be able to point me in the right direction for a fix for this?

Thanks for any thoughts.

***Edit*** - I looked further into it and I think it has something to do with my CSS.  I disabled css in ie8, and every link is clickable, even the ones that were difficult to locate earlier.  I guess there must be an overlapping of containers or something, so I will have to start messing around with those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  In the style.css file for my theme, the .block had position: relative; applied to it.  removing that bit of themeing appears to have fixed the link issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a CSS thing, have you inspected the elements in question using the developer tools (press F12) to see whats going on?

Comment: yeah - that's what I've been doing.  I'm looking at all of the css now.